# Default parameter and generic class

Tags: c++, generics, comparator

```
template <type1 _Type1, type2 _Comparator=...  >
```

I am trying to implement a class. the first parameter can be a string, a set or a list. The second parameter is a comparator. I would like to use the comparator < as a default parameter for type2.

I did not find the correct syntax for this, may you help me please?

**EDIT:** the answer given was good but not in my case.
I realized that I was looking for:

```
template <typename _Type, typename _Comparator=less<typename _Type::value_type> >
```

and not

```
template< class Type1, class Comparator = std::less<Type1> >
```

Because I need to compare elements which are part of the _Type.

Comment: how about `std::less<type1>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I *think* this may be what you're after:

```
template< class Type1, class Comparator = std::less<Type1> >
```

Note that names starting with underscore followed by uppercase are reserved to the implementation.

[`std::less`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) is declared by the `<functional>` header.